# sddm not starting - Failed to read display number from pipe

Tags: nvidia, kubuntu, sddm

I have a problem that is driving me crazy and could not find a solution in the web jet, so I would appreciate if anyone can point me in the right direction.
I have a laptop MSI prestige running kubuntu 22.04. I had to install kernel 5.18 so that the wifi work. I also installed nvidia drivers 515.48 (this solved some heating problems that I had).
So now it seems that everything runs good, but for a small random problem: plasma does not always start automatically. Usually, when the computer boots sddm fails so I have to change to another console, restart sddm and everything works fine. That is the usual procedure, but sometimes sddm starts good by itself on boot and sometimes everything is stuck and I have to reboot the computer.
The error I see in syslo is

```
sddm[1002]: Failed to read display number from pipe 
sddm[1002]: Could not start Display server on vt 1
```

Some of the parameters I have in grub that I read could help:

```
ibt=off rd.driver.blacklist=nouveau nvidia-drm.modeset=1
```

I read that it could be related to the fact sddm is launched prior to GPU being properly initialised, but not sure if it is really that and how to correct it.

So if anyone has some ideas, that would be great

`journalctl -b0 -u sddm.service`

gives

```
jul 03 13:33:44 valinor systemd[1]: Starting Simple Desktop Display Manager...
jul 03 13:33:44 valinor systemd[1]: Started Simple Desktop Display Manager.
jul 03 13:33:44 valinor sddm[1002]: Initializing...
jul 03 13:33:44 valinor sddm[1002]: Starting...
jul 03 13:33:44 valinor sddm[1002]: Logind interface found
jul 03 13:33:44 valinor sddm[1002]: Adding new display on vt 1 ...
jul 03 13:33:44 valinor sddm[1002]: Loading theme configuration from ""
jul 03 13:33:44 valinor sddm[1002]: Display server starting...
jul 03 13:33:44 valinor sddm[1002]: Adding cookie to "/var/run/sddm/{025b077b-f1fd-44f3-8b88-0a9cb7b3af50}"
jul 03 13:33:44 valinor sddm[1002]: Running: /usr/bin/X -nolisten tcp -auth /var/run/sddm/{025b077b-f1fd-44f3-8b88-0a9cb7b3af50} -background none -noreset -displayfd 17 -seat seat0 vt1
jul 03 13:33:44 valinor sddm[1002]: Failed to read display number from pipe
jul 03 13:33:44 valinor sddm[1002]: Could not start Display server on vt 1
jul 03 13:34:39 valinor sddm[1002]: Signal received: SIGTERM
jul 03 13:34:39 valinor systemd[1]: Stopping Simple Desktop Display Manager...
jul 03 13:34:39 valinor systemd[1]: sddm.service: Deactivated successfully.
jul 03 13:34:39 valinor systemd[1]: Stopped Simple Desktop Display Manager.
jul 03 13:34:40 valinor systemd[1]: Starting Simple Desktop Display Manager...
jul 03 13:34:40 valinor systemd[1]: Started Simple Desktop Display Manager.
jul 03 13:34:40 valinor sddm[1384]: Initializing...
jul 03 13:34:40 valinor sddm[1384]: Starting...
jul 03 13:34:40 valinor sddm[1384]: Logind interface found
jul 03 13:34:40 valinor sddm[1384]: Adding new display on vt 1 ...
jul 03 13:34:40 valinor sddm[1384]: Loading theme configuration from ""
jul 03 13:34:40 valinor sddm[1384]: Display server starting...
jul 03 13:34:40 valinor sddm[1384]: Adding cookie to "/var/run/sddm/{be1b0a15-08c9-4487-9982-0b6bfe194842}"
jul 03 13:34:40 valinor sddm[1384]: Running: /usr/bin/X -nolisten tcp -auth /var/run/sddm/{be1b0a15-08c9-4487-9982-0b6bfe194842} -background none -noreset -displayfd 17 -seat seat0 vt1
jul 03 13:34:41 valinor sddm[1384]: Setting default cursor
jul 03 13:34:42 valinor sddm[1384]: Running display setup script  "/usr/share/sddm/scripts/Xsetup"
jul 03 13:34:44 valinor sddm[1384]: Display server started.
jul 03 13:34:44 valinor sddm[1384]: Socket server starting...
jul 03 13:34:44 valinor sddm[1384]: Socket server started.
jul 03 13:34:44 valinor sddm[1384]: Loading theme configuration from "/usr/share/sddm/themes/ubuntu-theme/theme.conf"
jul 03 13:34:44 valinor sddm[1384]: Greeter starting...
jul 03 13:34:44 valinor sddm-helper[1473]: [PAM] Starting...
jul 03 13:34:44 valinor sddm-helper[1473]: [PAM] Authenticating...
jul 03 13:34:44 valinor sddm-helper[1473]: [PAM] returning.
jul 03 13:34:44 valinor sddm-helper[1473]: pam_unix(sddm-greeter:session): session opened for user sddm(uid=119) by (uid=0)
jul 03 13:34:44 valinor sddm[1384]: Greeter session started successfully
jul 03 13:34:44 valinor sddm[1384]: Message received from greeter: Connect
jul 03 13:34:48 valinor sddm[1384]: Message received from greeter: Login
jul 03 13:34:48 valinor sddm[1384]: Reading from "/usr/share/xsessions/plasma.desktop"
jul 03 13:34:48 valinor sddm[1384]: Reading from "/usr/share/xsessions/plasma.desktop"
jul 03 13:34:48 valinor sddm[1384]: Session "/usr/share/xsessions/plasma.desktop" selected, command: "/usr/bin/startplasma-x11"
jul 03 13:34:48 valinor sddm-helper[1548]: [PAM] Starting...
jul 03 13:34:48 valinor sddm-helper[1548]: [PAM] Authenticating...
jul 03 13:34:48 valinor sddm-helper[1548]: [PAM] Preparing to converse...
jul 03 13:34:48 valinor sddm-helper[1548]: [PAM] Conversation with 1 messages
jul 03 13:34:48 valinor sddm-helper[1548]: pam_kwallet5(sddm:auth): pam_kwallet5: pam_sm_authenticate
jul 03 13:34:48 valinor sddm-helper[1548]: [PAM] returning.
jul 03 13:34:48 valinor sddm[1384]: Authenticated successfully
jul 03 13:34:48 valinor sddm-helper[1548]: pam_kwallet5(sddm:setcred): pam_kwallet5: pam_sm_setcred
jul 03 13:34:48 valinor sddm-helper[1548]: pam_unix(sddm:session): session opened for user morales(uid=1000) by (uid=0)
jul 03 13:34:48 valinor sddm-helper[1548]: pam_kwallet5(sddm:session): pam_kwallet5: pam_sm_open_session
jul 03 13:34:48 valinor sddm-helper[1548]: Starting: "/etc/sddm/Xsession \"/usr/bin/startplasma-x11\""
jul 03 13:34:48 valinor sddm[1384]: Session started
jul 03 13:34:48 valinor sddm[1384]: Auth: sddm-helper exited successfully
jul 03 13:34:48 valinor sddm[1384]: Greeter stopped.
```

remark that it fails at start and the I manually restarted sddm

`egrep 'EE|WW' /var/log/Xorg.0.log`

```
[    60.502] Current Operating System: Linux valinor 5.18.0-051800-generic #202205222030 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Sun May 22 20:33:46 UTC 2022 x86_64
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    60.503] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[    60.503] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[    60.503] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[    60.503] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[    60.503] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[    60.693] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[    61.194] (WW) NVIDIA(G0): Unable to get display device for DPI computation.
[    61.324] (II) Initializing extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[    77.145] (WW) Option "xkb_variant" requires a string value
[    77.145] (WW) Option "xkb_options" requires a string value
[  2414.441] (EE) event10 - MSNB0001:00 06CB:CDAA Touchpad: kernel bug: Touch jump detected and discarded.
[  2545.249] (EE) event10 - MSNB0001:00 06CB:CDAA Touchpad: kernel bug: Touch jump detected and discarded.
[  2550.256] (EE) modeset(0): Failed to set CTM property: -13
[  2550.257] (EE) modeset(0): failed to set mode: No such file or directory
[  2583.546] (WW) Option "xkb_variant" requires a string value
[  2583.546] (WW) Option "xkb_options" requires a string value
```

I add `cat /var/log/gpu-manager.log`

```
log_file: /var/log/gpu-manager.log
last_boot_file: /var/lib/ubuntu-drivers-common/last_gfx_boot
new_boot_file: /var/lib/ubuntu-drivers-common/last_gfx_boot
can't access /opt/amdgpu-pro/bin/amdgpu-pro-px
Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/5.18.0-051800-generic/kernel
Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/5.18.0-051800-generic/updates/dkms
Found nvidia.ko module in /lib/modules/5.18.0-051800-generic/updates/dkms/nvidia.ko
Looking for amdgpu modules in /lib/modules/5.18.0-051800-generic/kernel
Looking for amdgpu modules in /lib/modules/5.18.0-051800-generic/updates/dkms
Is nvidia loaded? yes
Was nvidia unloaded? no
Is nvidia blacklisted? no
Is intel loaded? yes
Is radeon loaded? no
Is radeon blacklisted? no
Is amdgpu loaded? no
Is amdgpu blacklisted? no
Is amdgpu versioned? no
Is amdgpu pro stack? no
Is nouveau loaded? no
Is nouveau blacklisted? yes
Is nvidia kernel module available? yes
Is amdgpu kernel module available? no
Vendor/Device Id: 8086:46a6
BusID "PCI:0@0:2:0"
Is boot vga? yes
Vendor/Device Id: 10de:25a2
BusID "PCI:1@0:0:0"
can't open /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/boot_vga
Is boot vga? no
can't open /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/boot_vga
Chassis type: "10"
Laptop detected
can't access /etc/u-d-c-nvidia-runtimepm-override file
Found json file: /usr/share/doc/nvidia-driver-515-server/supported-gpus.json
File /usr/share/doc/nvidia-driver-515-server/supported-gpus.json not found
Is nvidia runtime pm supported for "0x25a2"? yes
Trying to create new file: /run/nvidia_runtimepm_supported
Checking power status in /proc/driver/nvidia/gpus/0000:01:00.0/power
Runtime D3 status:          Enabled (fine-grained)
Is nvidia runtime pm enabled for "0x25a2"? yes
Trying to create new file: /run/nvidia_runtimepm_enabled
Skipping "/dev/dri/card1", driven by "i915"
Skipping "/dev/dri/card0", driven by "nvidia-drm"
Skipping "/dev/dri/card1", driven by "i915"
Skipping "/dev/dri/card0", driven by "nvidia-drm"
Skipping "/dev/dri/card1", driven by "i915"
Skipping "/dev/dri/card0", driven by "nvidia-drm"
Found "/dev/dri/card1", driven by "i915"
output 0:
        card1-eDP-1
output 1:
        card1-DP-1
Number of connected outputs for /dev/dri/card1: 2
Does it require offloading? no
last cards number = 2
Has amd? no
Has intel? yes
Has nvidia? yes
How many cards? 2
Has the system changed? No
Takes 0ms to wait for nvidia udev rules completed.
Intel IGP detected
NVIDIA hybrid system
Creating /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/11-nvidia-offload.conf
Setting power control to "auto" in /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/power/control
```

and `dkms status`

```
nvidia/515.48.07, 5.15.0-39-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia/515.48.07, 5.18.0-051800-generic, x86_64: installed
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us `journalctl -b0 -u sddm.service` after a fail start. And `egrep 'EE|WW' /var/log/Xorg.0.log` s

Comment: Any chance you have an own Xorg.conf? can you also add `cat /var/log/gpu-manager.log` please and `dkms status`   i hope someone with more knowledge as me comes along.

Comment: I added the output. I don't think I have a custom Xorg.conf. I did not edit it.

Answer (score 0):

I begin to think that the problem is related to this issue:
https://github.com/sddm/sddm/issues/1316

In fast computer the start of sddm happens too fast.

I have delayed the start of sddm by 10 seconds. Up to now, I booted my computer twice and everything seems to work and sddm started by itself.